Clarification on OAuth2 Authentication - grant_type = password
I'm currently working on triggering an API (Fabric Job Scheduler in this case), which, as of now, doesn't support service principal authentication. To work around this, I've been trying to obtain an Access Token for an individual user without MFA using the following endpoint:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token

Here's the body of the request I'm using:
client_id=<clientid>&username=<username>&password=<password>&scope=https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/Workspace.ReadWrite.All https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/Item.ReadWrite.All https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/DataPipeline.Execute.All&grant_type=password&client_secret=<secret>

I'm trying to understand the rationale behind requiring both user credentials (username and password) as well as client credentials (Client ID and Client Secret) for authentication in this scenario. What is the purpose of combining these two forms of authentication, and are there specific security or operational reasons for this requirement; why can't the auth token be generated solely based on username and password?
Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

ROPC is deprecated and is actually removed entirely from OAuth2.1 - why are you using it?

@Dai, Unfortunately, Microsoft's new product which is fabric APIs doesn't support SP authentication, and only supports username and password. Hence, we are forced to try out this nonsecure method.

When you use grant_type = password means you are using Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC)

trying to understand the rationale behind requiring both user credentials (username and password) as well as client credentials (Client ID and Client Secret) for authentication

By managing the user's password directly, ROPC enables an application to log them in.
From this MS document  you can see, Client Secret is only applicable when your app is confidential client not when app is a public client.


I am clear with respect to when when to use the client secret. My query is more on ClientId. The ask here is what exactly is the role of clientId (even when if it is a public or private client) because the clientId has no role/permission on the api which I am trying to access. Is it just acting as a gateway/bridge between the username and the AAD to generate the Auth Token for the username provided.

@AhwanMishra client_id is often used for the same reasons as the User-Agent header in HTTP: client-identification is generally useful. Azure Entra requires client_id to be registered anyway, which helps with abuse prevention and bug-mitigation (as they can simply block a particular client_id from authenticating or by handling it differently somehow).
